# What happens to a bounty when a question is closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, bounty

So I recently posted an answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/cheap-programmable-portable-device). At the time I posted it, it had a 50 rep bounty on it. I knew it was a "shopping" question, but decided to post anyway.

Now, it's been closed by a diamond mod. No sign of the bounty having been awarded or existing. What happened to the bounty? Is this the one and only case where the bounty rep goes back to the user who posted it?

Answer (score 3):

The bounty was refunded.

You're right, the question isn't really a good fit for the site, and it should have been closed long ago (ideally it shouldn't have been migrated from SO at all). But, it managed to slip through the cracks and the bounty and the subsequent answers brought it to our attention. The bounty had to be refunded, as questions with active bounties can't be voted to close.

The closure also locked the question, as it became a rejected migration. Since the original version of the question on SO is deleted, I unlocked it. You and the other answerers may have lost the chance to win a bounty, but there's no reason your answers shouldn't get voted on.